# recreating in matlab Butterworth Filter filter response

Tags: butterworth

There is a manual which presents a filter response. In the video they present a formula and  a plot of the response. However when I tried to implement it in MATLAB I get a totally different plot.
Where did I go wrong implementing this formula?
Thanks.

```
clc
clear all
s=0:0.01:50;
H=1./((s/20.01).^4+2.6131*(s/20.01).^3+3.4142*(s/20.01).^2+2.6131*(s/20.01)+1);
plot(s,20*log10(abs(H)))
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3yyp5JRqNXs&list=PLdciPPorsHunK-nh9PyXcA8rTy4m-TuOV&index=4
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was hesitant to answer your question because it shows that you need to review the basics. However, hopefully this will encourage you to do just that!

---

The $s$ in $H(s)$ is a **complex number** $$s = \sigma + j\omega$$ where $\sigma$, the real part, represents a *damping* factor and $j\omega$, the imaginary part, represents an oscillatory component (for which $\omega$ is the angular frequency).

For sinusoidal steady-state analysis, we are interested in the behavior of the system at different frequencies but without the damping effect ($\sigma = 0$).

With that said, you only need minimal changes to your script:

```matlab
omega = 0:0.01:50;
s = 1i * omega;
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, i have attached the updated code ,however its not giving the result.
also ,i am new to he forum ,how do i put code in comment?
'clc
clear all
w=0:0.01:50;
s=1i*w;
H=1./((s/20.01).^4+2.6131*(s/20.01).^3+3.4142*(s/20.01).^2+2.6131*(s/20.01)+1);
plot(s,20*log10(abs(H)))'

Comment: Code can be rendered with ` before and after. Your last line should have $\omega$ for the `x`-axis: `plot(w, 20*log10(abs(H)))`.